# Is necessary regenerate client when WSDL change your targetnamespace?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

I have a wsdl that changes the targetnamespace.

```
@WebService(serviceName = "Test", portName = "Test", targetNamespace = "http://test.com.ar")
```

to

```
@WebService(serviceName = "Test", portName = "Test", targetNamespace = "http://mytest.com.ar")
```

Need I to regenerate the classes of my client?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its upto you, if you want you can regenerate the client side code. Otherwise you will have to manually change the namespace in the client side code because on the client side it will be looking for your webservice on

```
"http://test.com.ar"
```

And actually your service would be at a different place

```
"http://mytest.com.ar"
```